# education in/on maths and history

Tags: prepositions

I do not find a clear answer in internet, whether I should use **in** or **on**:

> *he had a broad education **in***  or  ***on** maths and history*

Could you help to choose the preposition?
(perhaps both are right :))

Comment: Your fragment doesn't sound like a likely sequence to me.Can you give a more complete context and intended meaning? Google Books records *no* instances of *the education is **on** history* (or the same with ***in***). I won't bother searching for the same for ***maths*** (which would normally be ***math*** in AmE), but I'm sure it won't be much different.

Comment: You are right, I just tried to make the sentence as short as possible. I think know you see more the context. By the way, yes, of course, maths is in BrE. :)

Comment: My first impression is that *maths and history* hardly counts as a "broad" education, and personally I simply wouldn't be likely to use your phrasing anyway (though I might well say *he had a broad education **including** maths and history*). But the short answer is that if you insist on getting a preposition in there, it would almost always be ***in***. Compare Google Books results for [an education in science](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an+education+in+science%22) (about 9400 hits) to ***one single hit*** for the same with ***on***.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your time. I will keep ***in*** in my text. Obviously I am not a native speaker, but putting ***including*** there feels unsuitable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not *on*. *In* is a good choice since education in your example seems to be *institutional education*. As in

> Education in Math, Science and Technology

*About* is also possible although it implies *general knowledge* and is more commonly used after *educated*.

Comment: Yeah, I think you got the point of my question. It referred to the education received in a certain institution, e.g., university